# Given a list of numbers find all the permutations that add to 100 of a certain length

Tags: python, list, permutation

Given a list of numbers, `list = [0,1,2,10,21,25,30,33,34,35]`, I want to find all the permutations of those numbers that sum to 100 on python.

However I would like to be able to use the values in the list more than once and I want  to be able to select the length of the permutation.

For example if the length of the permutation was 3, I would return: `[[30, 35, 35], [33, 33, 34], [33, 34, 33], [34, 33, 33], [35, 30, 35], [35, 35, 30]]`.

I have already been able to do this for length 3. However to do so I found all the combinations of 3 numbers that sum to 100 and then filtered through that to remove solutions that contain numbers outside of my original list.

The issue is that I cannot follow this approach for permutations of length 4,5,6 as there are a lot more combinations.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Show what you have tried so far (code). Read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: And are you sure you want changed-order-repeats? You've said you've got 6 answers for length 3 but it's actually just 2 combos with the numbers in a different order: **1.** 30 x1, 35 x2: `[30, 35, 35], [35, 30, 35], [35, 35, 30]` **2.** 33 x2, 34 x1: `[33, 33, 34], [33, 34, 33], [34, 33, 33]`.

Comment: @aneroid - yes i realised i actually only wanted the case that gives 2 elements out. but the solution that anyrg gave is fine as its quite easy to get rid of the duplicate cases. ty

Comment: Instead of getting rid of the duplicates - and there will be many as the size/length grows - use something that doesn't generate duplicates in the first place. Use @anyryg's solution but with [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) instead of `itertools.product`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but try this:

```
from itertools import product

def special_permutation(lst, rno, suma):
  results = []
  for c in product(lst, repeat = rno):
      if sum(c) == suma:
        results.append(c)
  return results
```

Comment: Please read the question attentively. This brute force approach is exactly what the OP says he can't use: "The issue is that I cannot follow this approach for permutations of length 4,5,6 as there are a lot more combinations."

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Actually, this answer isn't wrong as does not do what the OP did, which was _"I found all the combinations of 3 numbers that sum to 100 and then filtered through that to remove solutions that contain numbers outside of my original list."_ So basically, OP probably found all combos of `list(range(100))` which is why brute forcing didn't work. There are non-brute force options of course, but in the brute-force category, OP's brute-force was too brute. This answer only brute-forces the given list, and tbh, work just fine.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille  - this method works. It doesn't use the same brute forcing as I did. I guess its a little less brute which is why it works. Basically what aneroid said. Ty

Comment: As an example of how well this solution works: `%timeit` for 3: `180 µs ± 4.59 µs`; for 6: `242 ms ± 4.24 ms` and if I loop for 3, 4, 5, and 6: `994 ms ± 32.2 ms`. OP's _possible approach_ (undocumented, and I didn't add code to filter out incorrect numbers for correct sums): `%timeit` for 3: `174 ms ± 4.01 ms` (OP is ~**1,000x** slower); for 6: no idea, I hit Ctrl+C after 5 minutes. No doubt, a fully non-brute solution would be faster than this one, but the assertion that brute force can't be used for this is incorrect.